# SSLPassPhraseDialog: file '/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog' does not exist

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, httpd, openssl

When I'm starting apache with this command `sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -k start`,  I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 18 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
SSLPassPhraseDialog: file '/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog' does not exist
```

I see the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file is requesting access to this file:

```
#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
```

But I don't know where this file should be getting from, is that file supposed to have been installed with apache or mod_ssl?

Comment: On my CentOS 7 system `rpm -qf /usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog` indicates that it indeed should be included in the 
`mod_ssl` package.